# How to add break to page between parts in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a page, but for some reason content is not going down but it's going to right. I have tried to use tag **br** but it's now working.

Why is this happening? and... how do I fix it?

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

{% include "parts/text_story1.html" %}
<br>
{% include "parts/text_story2.html" %}
<br>

      <p>
            <form action="{% url "upload_story" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ message }}
            <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>

            <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>

            <p>
                  {{ form.docfile.errors }}
                  {{ form.docfile }}
            </p>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Upload Story!"/></p>
            </form>
      </p>

{% endblock content %}
```

This is how it looks, now it's not important to styling a details but this is a bigger problem.

[image]

Comment: Why is it horizontal at all? You might be wrapping it all in a ```display: flex``` container. Does either ```base.html``` have anything before ```{% block content %}``` or have a navbar improperly formatted? Or does ```text_storybook1.html``` have any ```display: flex``` that's unclosed?

Comment: could please show the templates that you included ?

Comment: @sin tribu iz was a flex, thank you very much. If you want, put answer, I'll vote up.

Comment: It' cool, thanks though! Glad its fixed.